# What is the best solution "going to or present progressive "for a future event in this case

Tags: future-tense

Shall I say

Next monday they are operating my arm or they are going to operate my arm

I think the first one is better because it is stronger than an intention .We can suppose the date was fixed and we can't change it

Comment: Regardless of the tense (and both are fine), it should be *(operate/operating) **on** my arm.*

Answer (score 1):

They both work equally well. So does "they will operate".

However, it's "operate **on** my arm". *Operate* is transitive for machinery ("Do you know how to operate a sewing machine?"), but not for surgery.

So the sentence would be one of these:

- "Next Monday, they're operating on my arm."
- "Next Monday, they're going to operate on my arm."
- "Next Monday, they'll operate on my arm."